# PHP Session not carrying over to protected pages

Tags: php, session

I've been having a really rough time trying to implement a logon system for my web application.

I have the basic logic working as far as my index.php goes - if users try to navigate there and are not logged in it redirects them to the logon screen. Once they've provided correct credentials they are directed properly back to the protected index.php page.

This logic in code is seen here:

**(index.php**)

```
    <?php
    session_start();
    include_once 'db_functions.php';
    require_once 'access.php';

    if (!userIsLoggedIn()) {
        include 'login.php';
        exit();
    }
```

The problem occurs when a user attempts to navigate to another protected page. My logic was for protected pages to check whether the user was logged in, and if not send them back to the index which would in turn send them to a logon screen.

**(protectedpage.php)**

```
   <?php
    session_start();
    require_once 'access.php';
    echo "Logged in: " + $_SESSION['loggedIn'];
    echo "User: " + $_SESSION['email'];
    echo "Password: " + $_SESSION['password'];
    // receive data from HTML readcalllog request

    $rName=$_POST["registration"]; //irrelevant post data
    $rowId=$_POST["rowid"]; //irrelevant post data

    if ($_SESSION['loggedIn'] == FALSE) {
        header('Location: http://www.myapp.com/index.php'); //if not logged in, return to index.php, which in turn redirects to a logon page. 
        exit();
    }
```

As you can see I included test echo statements to print out the details of the current session. When I would navigate to the page (turning off the redirect feature) to check the error messages it would print `"000"`, without the `"Logged in: "` or `"User: "` text in front of it.

I performed a test and printed out the details successfully on the index.php page, so for some reason the session is being lost as I navigate from index.php to another protected page.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**EDIT:**
Here is a portion of the userIsLoggedIn() in `access.php` function which sets the session variables:

```
function userIsLoggedIn()
{
    if (databaseContainsAuthor($_POST['email'], $password))
    {
      session_start();
      $_SESSION['loggedIn'] = TRUE;
      $_SESSION['email'] = $_POST['email'];
      $_SESSION['password'] = $password;
      return TRUE;
    }
    else
    {
      session_start();
      unset($_SESSION['loggedIn']);
      unset($_SESSION['email']);
      unset($_SESSION['password']);
      $GLOBALS['loginError'] =
          'The specified email address or password was incorrect.';
      return FALSE;
    }
  }
}
```

**EDIT 2:**
If I login to the index page, go to the protected page(which sends me to a logon screen) and login again, the sessions function properly and all protected pages are accessible. 
I just need to figure out what's preventing the initial logon from creating a proper session that carries over.

Comment: how does your login look like

Comment: the only difference I see between the two files is `include_once 'db_functions.php';`: are you sure there's nothing important in `db_functions.php` or have you tried to include it in `protectedpage.php` too?

Comment: These are not the complete files, only snippets of the portions that apply to sessions and logging in.

Comment: U should use `userIsLoggedIn` also in your protected pages instead of the `$_SESSION['loggedIn'] === FALSE` tho

Comment: Dont use session_start more than once a request. Just put it as first line. Not in your loggedin function. It will produce an notice otherwise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you do not need to include `session_start();` more then once in a page. Just insert it at the beginning of each file.

If I were you, I would use this statement to see if the user is logged in or not in the protected pages:

```
    if ( !isset($_SESSION['email'] && !isset($_SESSION['password'] ) ) {
        header('Location: http://www.myapp.com/index.php'); //if not logged in, return to index.php, which in turn redirects to a logon page. 
        exit();
    } else {
        echo "Logged in";
    }
```

Also, I would recommend you using both `$_SESSION` and `$_COOKIES` to create a stronger log in system.